# How to limit selectable to 1 day OR add constraint to dayClick?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Using fullcalendar: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectable
                    https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick

So I'm trying to add an action so that when the user clicks on a day something happens. I've tried:

```
selectable: true,
            selectOverlap: false,
            select: function (selectInfo) {
                if (selectInfo.start.getDate != selectInfo.end.getDate) {
                    calendar.unselect();
                }
            },
            eventConstraint: {
                start: '00:00',
                end: '24:00',
            },
```

So the good thing is that I have the selectOverlap: false which I want. But the user can still select more day. The other thing I tried was with:

```
dateClick: function (info) {
                //var test = calendar.getElementById('forbidden');
                /*if (info.dateStr == event.start) {
                    alert('TEST!!!!!!');
                }*/
                alert('Clicked on: ' + info.dateStr);
                alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
                alert('Current view: ' + info.view.type);
                // change the day's background color just for fun
                info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

            },
```

So I tried to give an id: 'forbidden' so that I know if there is already an event there but it didn't work...basically I was trying to use the selectOverlap: false but for dayClick. The good thing is with this the user can only select 1 day but he should not be able to click on it if there is already an event then (or if the entire day is forbidden...can I get even.overlap == false somehow ?).

Comment: So you want to only allow one event to exist per day, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Only 1 event per day and let the user create a new one either by using the selectable method or the dateClick. With selectable he can select as many days as he wants not good...and with dateClick at least he can click only 1 but he can also click on red areas where overlap is not allowed...with selectable i've managed to make an exception for no overlap allowed

Comment: I think you'd have to get all the events on the calendar, loop through them and check the date of each one, to see if it overlaps with the date the user is trying to add to. fullCalendar doesn't have any built-in support for this kind of validation - as you know, it can help you detect overlaps, but cannot deal with the number of events per day. (N.B. you might want to consider just doing this server-side, since you'd have to do that anyway to ensure integrity once the event data was submitted).